# how to get request headers in php using any url like(www.w3schools.com)

Tags: php

how to get request headers in php using any url give the details like this(Pragma,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Host,Accept-Language,User-Agent,Accept,Cache-Control,Connection) give the value.

Comment: Did you look at the manual? [Request](http://se1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: After Goggling your question this is the first link that comes up. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-headers.php

Comment: your url not working (http://se1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php%5D%28Request%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
    ?>
```

Comment: sir how to pass url like(www.w3schools.com) in <?php echo"<pre>";print_r($_SERVER);?>

Comment: how to pass any url like (www.w3schools.com) in the <?php 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
    ?>

Comment: What you want to do ? I am not getting you.

Comment: i want to make a program in this program we give pass any url name like(www.stackoverflow.com) get request headers value like (Pragma,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Host,Accept-Language,User-Agent,Accept,Cache-Control,Connection,etc) that url